# Adjust formula automatically based on OptionButton choice

Tags: vba, radio-button

My Excel model allows the user to calculate delivery costs for different product categories in different countries. The choice is made via option buttons on a userform:
Frame 1: USA, UK or Germany
Frame 2: Books, Fashion or Grocery

Let's say the user has chosen USA as a country and Books as product category. 
I now use formulas, such as salary_USA / 365, whereas "salary_USA" is a pre-defined range name.
I also copy and paste certain values from an assumption sheet: Worksheets("Assumptions Books").Range("E34:J34").Copy

If the user chooses UK, the formula changes to salary_UK / 365. If Germany is selected, the formula changes to salary_Germany / 365.

Similarly, if the selected product category is Fashion, it should be Worksheets("Assumptions Fashion").Range("E34:J34").Copy etc.

**How can I make these commands more flexible, i.e. responsive to the user's selection?**

I want to avoid to write a sub for each an every combination (USA-Books, USA-Fashion, USA-Grocery, UK-Books, UK-Fashion etc.)

---

I thought about defining a variabel as follows:

```
Public Country As String

Private Sub optUSA_Click()

If optUSA.Value = True Then
Country = "USA"
```

And then using this variable in the respective formula:

```
Sub CalculateCosts()

"salary_" & Country / 365
```

However, this approach does not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use all buttons to call the same macro and then, inside it reveald user choice. Look at this code below and test it in your app. It tells you which button was clicked.

```
  'Procedure to display which button was pressed.
  Sub WhichButton()

     ' Assign the calling object to a variable.
     ButtonName = Application.Caller

     ' Display the name of the button that was clicked.
     Select Case ButtonName

        ' NOTE: When you type the name of the button, note that
        ' Visual Basic is case and space sensitive when comparing                                                
        ' strings. For example, "Button 6" and "button6" are not the 
        ' same.
        Case "Button 6"
        MsgBox Application.Caller & "  was Clicked"

        Case "Button 7"
        MsgBox Application.Caller & " was clicked."

        Case "Button 8"
        MsgBox Application.Caller & " was clicked."

     End Select

  End Sub
```

You will find the code with full info here: http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/143345